# Redifinition of functions in derived class

Tags: c++

In C++ primer plus it is written that

"If you redefine just one version of function in derived class, the other functions of base class  become hidden and cannot be used by objects of the derived class."

Then why does this code call fun1() ,as it should be hidden for the derived class object i.e. obj.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
    public:
      void fun1()
    {
    cout<<"base"<<endl;

       }
        void fun2(int a)
       {
           cout<<"function2";
       }
};
class derived :public base
{
public:
 void fun2()
       {
           cout<<"fun2";
       }

   };

int main()
{
 derived obj;
 obj.fun1();
 }
```

Comment: Please learn to type code here...its hard to read your code this way and there are syntax error in your code (like the missing ; at the end of your derived class etc.). And can you quote the place from where you read it if its online?

Comment: @mtahmed:I am sorry.Actually I have just copied and posted.

Comment: No worries man, was just pointing you to the right way to do it in the future...

Answer (score 7):

When it says "the other functions of the base class become hidden" it actually means "the base class functions **with the same name** become hidden in the derived class".

So, if you declare two overloaded versions of `fun1` in the base class (say, `fun1(void)` and `fun1(int)`), and then declare another version of `fun1` in the derived class (say, `fun1(double)`), the function in the derived class will hide both `fun1` functions inherited from the base class.

In your example, the derived `fun2` hides the base `fun2`, but it doesn't hide base `fun1`. This is why you can successfully call `fun1` in your example.

You can observe the fact that derived `fun2` has hidden the base `fun2` by trying to call

```
obj.fun2(42);
```

Since the `fun2(int)` from the base class is hidden by `fun2(void)` from the derived class, the call will fail to compile.

Comment: Nice answer. The answer will be complete if you would add how to enable access to the hidden Base class member functions by using the using declaration.

Comment: @Als: Well, it appears that OP is reading a book. The book will probably cover this in due course.

Comment: Please, no fun1(void) in C++. It only serves to confuse.

Comment: @dascandy: I wanted to emphasize that was talking about a parameter-less function.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example you have not redefined fun1, but redefined fun2. so if you call fun1 it would still call the base class function. but if you call obj.fun2() it will class derived class function.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't redefined any version of `fun1`; you have only overloaded `fun2`. This doesn't hide everything in the base class; it hides the other overloads of the same function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a function in a derived class do something different to the parent class then you need to make the parent function virtual.

```
virtual void fun1() { ... }
```